# CSS and fixed navigation

Tags: css

I'm new to CSS and from the background of WPF/ Desktop apps.
I need to format the layout of the website exactly the same as client version (WPF). which is basically consists of three key areas:
1) The Bottom bar (25px height) for shows status messages and logo in right corner
2) The middle area with two cols (LeftNav and main-content). 
3) The header 
What I want is that the "Bottom bar" should always displayed and there should be a scrollbar if the contents enlarges the page height for main-contents.
Also the "LeftNav" should also appear bottom-aligned (like outlook) and grow upwards but covers the whole height upto the header section.
The main-content should be top aligned and starts after the header.
The header is of fixed height of 100PX.

Anyone can help me by sharing some css style to do this please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to position your header, footer and main container wrapper (containig left and right content) with absolute position. Footer `bottom: 0px;`, Header `top:0px;`.
It is also very important to declare `overflow: auto;` on the right or left middle container to get scroll when you will have content that exceeds the total height of the user screen.
If you have any other question feel free to ask

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response. I did works but what I want is the "main content" area (right side) to be shrink/expand if the left nav is opened/closed. At the moment I set it float:left and left:200px; which is the width of Left Nav. but when I hide the Left Nav with Jquery, it has the 200px blank space on left hand side. How can I make it dynamic?

Comment: try with javascript, setting the padding to 200px when the left panel is visible and to 0px when the pannel is hidden. it is very simple.

Comment: thanks for that. A couple of issues with regard to the middle section. I have the wrapper class which contains both "leftNav" and "maincontent" areas. I set the wrapper position to absolute with top:100px; height:100%; but this makes it grow under the footer div and no scrollbar turns up Although I have setup the overflow:auto on "maincontent". I think the height:100%; takes the height of full window. How can I make it to stretch only between header and footer? Also I want the leftNav to be bottom aligned as well and I set the vertical-align:bottom but it still starts from top.

Comment: very simple. remove height:100% and add bottom: 100px if the height of the footer is 100px;

Comment: I already tried that but that did not work. But then I changed the footer position to fixed and its working (not growing under the footer). but the leftNav is still top aligned and does not connect with the bottom footer. I believe I have to move it out from the wrapper and make its position to absolute as well.